# How to access different target's class instance?

Tags: ios

I'm using Notification ContentExtension which is in the different target from the main target.

I want to access and call the method of AppDelegate located in the main target from the different target.

Is this possible?
I tried with `notification-observer pattern` but it doesn't seem to reach to main target's instance. It seems like they are working separately.

NOTE: I'm NOT asking a way to share a file in different targets.

Comment: maybe it https://github.com/choefele/CCHDarwinNotificationCenter

Comment: @GIJOW thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMWormhole is a great tool to do just this. It's just like `NotificationCenter` but with the added benefit that the notifications can cross from an extensions target back to the main app's target.

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

(there are plenty of examples in the README for the project)

Comment: Seems like what I’m looking for. Thanks!